# Why is my image not resizing properly within the container

Tags: css, reactjs, image

I've used this code to automatically resize the image to fit the container it's in, this code is working in other areas of my site, so I have no idea why it's not working here. Am I missing something?

```
<div className='image-container'>
   <img src={imageRoutes} alt='post' />
</div>

.image-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

It's displaying the image to fit the container corner to corner without maintaining it's initial pixel ratio, so essentially it's stretching the images to 100% of the container width and a height of 400px.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: please provide an url insteaf of `{imageRoutes}` that gives us no clue what are you talking about

Comment: Sorry about that, the imageRoutes is just the image that's been uploaded using a input (type='file), so the image can be any size, none of them seem to be resizing properly.

Answer (score 0):

instead of :

```
.image-container img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

do:

```
.image-container img {
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```